# Is it possible to trigger some JavaScript when Media Popup is opened?

Tags: uploads, media, media-library, media-modal

On one of my custom posts edit page I have a button that triggers the media popup onclick, with: `wp.media.editor.open();` and while it brings up the media manager I'm not sure if that's the proper way to do it. Is it?

But real question is about something else. How do I attach event listeners to various events that media popup should trigger? Like `open` or `close` or is there any event for switched view?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use several event handlers.

```
frame.on('open',function() {
    // Do something
});

frame.on('close',function() {
    // Do something
});

frame.on('select',function() {
    // Do something
});
```

Where `frame` is a reference to `wp.media()`

```
frame = wp.media();

frame.on('select',function() {
    // Do something
});
```

---

Full example

Script en-queued with jQuery and media editor as dependencies.

```
function media_script_enqueue() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'media-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/media-script.js', array( 'jquery', 'media-editor' ), '', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'media_script_enqueue' ); // Front-end
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'media_script_enqueue' ); // Back-end
```

Script contains:

```
;( function( $ ) {
    var frame = wp.media({
         multiple: true
    });

    $(".media").on("click", function(e) {
        frame.open();

        e.preventDefault();
    });

    frame.on('open', function() {
        console.log("Open");
    });

    frame.on('close', function() {
        console.log("Close");
    });

    frame.on('select', function() {
        console.log("Select");

        var selection = frame.state().get('selection');

        selection.each(function(attachment) {
            console.log(attachment.id);
        });
    });
} )( jQuery );
```

Window triggered by a button with a classname of `media`

```
<button class="media">Media</button>
```

Media javascript dependencies enqueued via function.

```
<?php wp_enqueue_media(array('post' => get_the_ID())); ?>
```

Comment: do you mind making it fuller example? Where does this code goes, when should it be used (after load event, or is there some other trigger)?

Comment: You would use the admin_enqueue_scripts action in your plugin or theme to enqueue your JavaScript files that create this functionality. The JavaScript given in Rob's example can be executed at the point where you open the media manager.

Answer (score 0):

Last I checked the best documentation was the source code - see media-views.js, media-models.js here: http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/nav.html?wp-includes/js/

Experimenting with the console can be helpful - It's mostly backbone objects, you can watch events triggered using something like this script I made some time ago - http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/161075

Comment: Can you provide an example of how one is supposed to invoke your script (for backbone.js dummies...)

Comment: The eventslog is helpful to use like `eventslog('backboneobj',backboneobj,3)` or similar.